# Querying multiple related records in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have an `Account`, `User` and `Group` model. All `User` and `Group` records belong to an `Account`, so it is possible for both users and groups to be related to various accounts.

Basically, I have some really hacky, pieced together SQL queries that lookup all `Account` records related to a given `User` or `Group` record through various
associations.

Even though it's fast and only requires a single query for everything to work, I really hate the way it's written.

I was wondering if there is any way I could do this more *programatically* with something like `arel`, or if there was a better approach. I also have some security concerns about the code.

```rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :accountable, touch: true, polymorphic: true

  CLAUSE_FOR_RELATED = '"accounts"."accountable_type" = \'%s\' AND "accounts"."accountable_id" IN (%s)'.freeze

  def self.related_to_user(user)
    groups = user.groups.select('"groups".id')
    friends = user.following_friendships.select('"friendships".following_id')

    queries = []
    queries.push ['Group', groups.to_sql]
    queries.push ['User', friends.to_sql]
    queries.push ['User', user.id]

    self.related_to(queries)
  end

  def self.related_to_group(group)
    queries = [
      ['User', group.members.select('"users".id').to_sql]
    ]

    self.related_to(queries)
  end

  def self.related_to(queries)
    clauses = queries.map do |clause|
      sprintf(CLAUSE_FOR_RELATED, clause[0], clause[1])
    end

    self.where(clauses.join(" OR "))
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the SQL tag properly used here? Was looking for SQL to review in your code but found only tiny snippets. No bad karma just seems a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use as much as possible what is provided by `ActiveRecord`. I was thinking to something like:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accountable, touch: true, polymorphic: true
  CLAUSE_FOR_RELATED = '"accounts"."accountable_type" = \'%s\' AND "accounts"."accountable_id" IN (%s)'.freeze

  class << self
    def related_to_user(user)
      group_ids = user.groups.pluck('groups.id')
      friend_ids = user.following_friendships.pluck('friendships.following_id') 

      query = [
        compose_clause('Group', group_ids.join(', ')),
        compose_clause('User', [user.id, *friend_ids].join(', '))
      ].join(' or ')

      where(query)
    end

    def related_to_group(group)
      member_ids = group.members.pluck('users.id')
      where(compose_clause('User', member_ids.join(', ')))
    end

    private
    def compose_clause(accountable_type, ids)
      sprintf(CLAUSE_FOR_RELATED, accountable_type, ids)
    end
  end
end
```

Now in Rails 5 you could even write it like:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accountable, touch: true, polymorphic: true

  class << self
    def related_to_user(user)
      group_ids = user.groups.pluck('groups.id')
      friend_ids = user.following_friendships.pluck('friendships.following_id') 

      where(accountable_type: 'Group', accountable_id: group_ids).or(
         Account.where(accountable_type: 'User', accountable_id: [user.id, *friend_ids])
      )
    end

    def related_to_group(group)
      member_ids = group.members.pluck('users.id')
      where(accountable_type: 'User', accountable_id: member_ids)
    end
  end
end
```